# Imagens no ListView recarregando toda vez que seleciono o fragment?

Tags: java, android, xml

Estou usando o batch drawable importer para gerar diferentes imagens de acordo com o dpi. Cada imagem original tem a resolução de 1920x1080 com um tamanho médio de 350kb. Porém, é gerado uma imagem com um tamanho enorme de 4mb na pasta de xxxhdpi. (Isso é normal? ou deveria usar imagens originais menores?)

O problema é que parece que o aplicativo demora um pouco pra abrir o fragment que contém a lista de imagens. Para tentar resolver isso, usei o Picasso. Entretanto, apesar de agora eu conseguir abrir rapidamente o fragment, as imagens demoram um pouco pra carregar e isso acontece sempre que saio e volto do mesmo.

Seria isso um problema no cache ou do fato de eu estar usando imagens com uma alta resolução?

> Custom ListView Adapter:

```
public class CustomListaImagens extends BaseAdapter {

    String[] tituloServico;
    Integer[] images;

    Context context;

    public CustomListaImagens(String[] tituloServico, Integer[] images, Context context) {
        this.tituloServico = tituloServico;
        this.images = images;
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_imagens_layout, parent, false);
        TextView textView =  rowView.findViewById(R.id.servico_titulo_id);
        ImageView imageView =  rowView.findViewById(R.id.imagem_servico_id);

        textView.setText(tituloServico[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);

        return rowView;
    }

}
```

> Layout da Lista de Imagens Customizada XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_lista_id"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
        android:elevation="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagem_servico_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/background1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/servico_titulo_id"
            fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@color/backgroundText"
            android:elevation="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="BELEZA"
            android:textColor="@color/Texto"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imagem_servico_id"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imagem_servico_id"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imagem_servico_id"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imagem_servico_id"
            tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

> Activity principal onde os fragments são carregados:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private BottomNavigationViewEx bottomNavigationViewEx;
        private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            firebaseAuth = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseAutenticacao();

            bottomNavigationViewEx = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav);
            BottomNavConfig.ConfigurarBottomNav(bottomNavigationViewEx);


            bottomNavigationViewEx.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    android.support.v4.app.Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.menu_pedidos:
                            selectedFragment = new PedidosFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.menu_home:
                            selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.menu_conta:
                            selectedFragment = new MinhaContaFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.menu_help:
                            selectedFragment = new AjudaFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.menu_procurar:
                            selectedFragment = new ProcurarFragment();
                            break;
                    }

                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    if (selectedFragment != null) {
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, selectedFragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            bottomNavigationViewEx.setSelectedItemId(R.id.menu_home);
        }

        @Override
        protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
            super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
        }

        public void IrParaLoginActivity() {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }
```

> Fragment onde contém a lista de imagens:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    List<Address> addresses;
    private Location location;

    private TextView tv_location;
    private String[] permissoesNecessarias = new String[]{
              Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
              Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    };

    private String[] TituloServico = {"BELEZA", "CASA", "INFORMATICA"};
    private Integer[] imagens = {R.drawable.beleza, R.drawable.casa, R.drawable.informatica};


    public HomeFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        Permissao.validaPermissoes(1,getActivity(), permissoesNecessarias);

        Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_home);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            ((MainActivity) Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }

        ListView listView = view.findViewById(R.id.lista_imagens_id);
        CustomListaImagens listaImagens = new CustomListaImagens(TituloServico, imagens, getActivity());
        listView.setAdapter(listaImagens);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                if (TituloServico[position] == "CASA") {
                   startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), CasaActivity.class));
                }
            }
        });

        tv_location = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_location_id);

        pegaLocalizacao();

        return view;
    }


    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        for(int resultado : grantResults) {
            if (resultado == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                alertaValidacaoPermissao();
            }
        }
    }

    public void alertaValidacaoPermissao() {
        android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Permissões Negadas");
        builder.setMessage("Para utilizar esse app é necessário aceitar as permissões");

        builder.setPositiveButton("CONFIRMAR", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                try {
                    finalize();
                } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                    throwable.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    }

    public void pegaLocalizacao() {
        try {
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            if (locationManager != null) {
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            }
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        tv_location.setText(cityName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Verifique se o seu fragment está chamando o método onStop.
inclua esse código no seu fragment.

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.e("Ciclo", "Activity: Metodo onResume() chamado");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.e("Ciclo", "Activity: Metodo onPause() chamado");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Log.e("Ciclo", "Activity: Metodo onSavedInstanceState() chamado");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.e("Ciclo", "Activity: Metodo onStop() chamado");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e("Ciclo", "Activity: Metodo onDestroy() chamado");
    }
```

Digite Ciclo no seu Logcat e analise se o método onStop está sendo chamado.